# How to quickly change the corresponding the eigenvectors by sorting eigenvalues in python？

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting, eigenvector

I am getting confused trying to change the corresponding the eigenvectors by sorting eigenvalues.

All eigenvalues：

```
 array([[[[-8.        , -0.        ,  4.        ],
     [-4.        , -3.        ,  4.        ],
     [-2.82842712, -0.        ,  2.82842712],
     [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  2.        ]],

    [[-4.        ,  0.        ,  4.        ],
     [-4.        ,  0.        ,  4.        ],
     [-2.        ,  0.        ,  2.        ],
     [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]]],


   [[[-4.        ,  0.        ,  4.        ],
     [-4.        ,  0.        ,  4.        ],
     [-2.        ,  0.        ,  2.        ],
     [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]],

    [[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
     [-4.        ,  0.        ,  4.        ],
     [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
     [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]]]])
```

After sorting eigenvalues('axis = -1' direction)：

```
   array([[[[-0.        ,  4.        , -8.        ],
     [-3.        , -4.        ,  4.        ],
     [-0.        , -2.82842712,  2.82842712],
     [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  2.        ]],

    [[ 0.        , -4.        ,  4.        ],
     [ 0.        , -4.        ,  4.        ],
     [ 0.        , -2.        ,  2.        ],
     [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]]],


   [[[ 0.        , -4.        ,  4.        ],
     [ 0.        , -4.        ,  4.        ],
     [ 0.        , -2.        ,  2.        ],
     [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]],

    [[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
     [ 0.        , -4.        ,  4.        ],
     [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
     [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]]]])
```

How can I get the corresponding eigenvector based on the sorting of eigenvalues?

The problem is that if I want to index the eigenvector corresponding to the maximum eigenvalue, will this eigenvector change because of the order inside the eigenvalue, then how do I get the corresponding eigenvector by column?

Please help! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi! The question is not clear to me! Do you have a matrix, and you're trying to get its eigenvectors and corresponding eigenvalues, and want to know which is the eigenvector corresponding to the max eigenvalue? Can you edit a bit your question to clarify, and maybe share more of the code you are using?